# Loop through records and their parents to find matching record

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these three tables:

```
items

id   parent_id
--------------
590  589
589  588
588  587
587  586

user_items

item_id   project_id   user_id
------------------------------
588       50           2
587       49           2

users

id
--
2
```

I need to find the user_item whose item_id either matches an item's id or an item's parent_id. It also needs to match the user_id.

This is the way it should work:

1) Starting with the item_id 590 and user_id 2, I query the user_items table. There are zero records.

2) I query the item with id 590 and find the item's parent_id, which is 589. I then take that parent_id as well as the user_id and query the user_items table again. There are zero records.

3) I then find the items record with the id 589. I use that record's parent_id (588) and query the user_items table again. There is a match, so it breaks the loop and returns that matching user_item.

Note that I have to use this schema, and it needs to return the first user_item that matches. There can be up to 5 levels of items and their parents.

At first I thought I could just use item 590 and all of its parents, but that would select too many user_items. It needs to return the lowest level item that matches. I also thought I could use a loop, but I'm unfamiliar with how that works, and I imagine there's an easier solution.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Postgresql, you'll want to use what is called a CTE, or common table expression.  Below is a snippet that I hope will be useful.

```
WITH RECURSIVE t(id, parent_id, path) AS (
    SELECT id, parent_id, ARRAY[id]
    FROM items
    WHERE id = 590
  UNION
    SELECT i.id, i.parent_id, i.parent_id || t.path
    FROM items i
    INNER JOIN t ON t.parent_id = i.id
)
SELECT items.* FROM items
INNER JOIN t ON t.id = items.id
INNER JOIN user_items ON user_items.item_id = items.id AND user_items.user_id = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use recursion to avoid needing a loop.  I would read up on the "with recursive" option in this postgresql article: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html

Once you connect all of your items/parents items together using recursion, you can limit the results to get only the one with a userid.

As a side note, recursion in Oracle is done by using the keywords "start with" and "connect by".